Trying to do join on two data frames getting error: "... float values are not equal to their int representation"
joined_df = Register.join(
    ledger,
    lsuffix='Register',
    rsuffix='ledger'
    on='Gross',
    how='left')

Getting below error
<ipython-input-63-87afd279f9b6>:1: UserWarning: You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation.
my data types of ledger
After changing datatypes also still getting this error. my gross is both dataframes float64

Please provide a [mre] (input + expected output)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

rsuffix='ledger' is missing a trailing comma, but I assume that's just a typo.

Let's say you're investigating suspicious transactions and want to match a Company in the Register dataframe to a Client in the ledger dataframe based on the Gross amount of the transaction:
Register = pd.DataFrame({
    'Company': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Gross': [1000.4, 0.0, 3000.1],
})

ledger = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gross': [1000.4, 3000.1, 0.0],
    'Client': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
})

You might try something like this:
Register.join(ledger,
    lsuffix='Register',
    rsuffix='ledger',
    on='Gross',
    how='left')

  Company  GrossRegister  Grossledger Client
0       A         1000.4          NaN    NaN
1       B            0.0       1000.4      X
2       C         3000.1          NaN    NaN
<ipython-input-82-3d8c02c1639e>:1: UserWarning: You are merging on int and float columns where the float values are not equal to their int representation.

As we can see, the join didn't work, and what is going on with company B?
Let's check the examples in the documentation for the DataFrame.join

Another option to join using the key columns is to use the on parameter. DataFrame.join always uses other’s index but we can use any column in df.

The reason for the warning is that your code isn't joining the two Gross columns (which are both float64), it's attempting to join the Gross column of the Register dataframe with the index of the ledger dataframe (which is an int), hence the warning.
To fix this, we need to set the index of the ledger dataframe to Gross:
Register.join(ledger.set_index('Gross'),
    on='Gross',
    lsuffix='Register',
    rsuffix='ledger',
    how='left')

  Company   Gross Client
0       A  1000.4      X
1       B     0.0      Z
2       C  3000.1      Y

On a side note, if the values in the Gross column were all integers, then Pandas wouldn't have given us any warnings at all, which would have made the issue harder to debug. I checked how  ChatGPT would answer your question and it suggested rounding the Gross amount, which might help prevent precision issues and make the warning go away if the Gross amounts all round to integers, but doesn't do what you want!
